# How do I encrypt/decrypt a file in .NetCore?

Tags: encryption, .net-core, encryption-symmetric

I would like to encrypt/decrypt a file to/from disk using .NetCore libraries.

Examples I have seen are account based so that only the account used to encrypt the file can decrypt it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=net-5.0

I need to be able to password encrypt my files.
Is there a .Net library available for that (either part of standard .NetCore libraries or 3rd party)?

Comment: @ArtjomB - I wasn't sure which way I wanted to go with it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are lots of resources for encryption/decryption on the internet and with a simple search, you can find them.

Encrypt:

```cs
public static string EncryptString(string text, string keyString)
{
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);

    using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        using (var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, aesAlg.IV))
        {
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(text);
                }

                var iv = aesAlg.IV;

                var decryptedContent = msEncrypt.ToArray();

                var result = new byte[iv.Length + decryptedContent.Length];

                Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(decryptedContent, 0, result, iv.Length, decryptedContent.Length);

                return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Decrypt:

```cs
public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, string keyString)
{
    var fullCipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

    var iv = new byte[16];
    var cipher = new byte[16];

    Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, iv.Length);
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);

    using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        using (var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
        {
            string result;
            using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
            {
                using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        result = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

[Symmetric and Asymmetric Encryption in .NET Core](https://damienbod.com/2020/08/19/symmetric-and-asymmetric-encryption-in-net-core/)

[Cryptography with Practical Examples in .Net Core](https://dev.to/stratiteq/cryptography-with-practical-examples-in-net-core-1mc4)

[Encryption And Decryption Using A Symmetric Key In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/encryption-and-decryption-using-a-symmetric-key-in-c-sharp/)

Comment: Thank you for the links to get me started. Q: To extend this, let's say I have a Sqlite DB I want to encrypt. I assume the way to go is to read in the DB file from disk, apply the encryption and then save the file. To decrypt I'd read in the file from disk, decrypt it and then write it out as decrypted before opening it?

Comment: `*.exe` also is a file on the disk, do you can open `exe` file and read it as a string to encrypt that?